# Best practice design pattern for an NPM+Webpack website

Tags: npm, webpack

I'm learning webpack, and this is a theoretical question. For each webpage in a site, I'm planning to make a page-specific module that itself will require a module for site-wide code. I'm planning to use webpack's splitChunks so that the sitewide code is saved to a separate bundle.js. In theory, is this plausible / best practice? I suppose the inverse is possible where the sitewide module is the main entry. Thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK I had my a-ha moment. Yes, each page in the site is an entry and needs to be registered as en entry in one main webpack.config.js. When I webpack the site, webpack will automatically split common code into chunks. Since each page will require the site-wide module, webpack will see that common dependency and optimize the chunks.

Comment: I realized that this isn't the complete solution for me. I do need multiple entries (one for each webpage), but I also need multiple outputs (one for each webpage). Need to keep on looking ...

Comment: a-ha. All I need to do is use [name] in the output path, webpack will create multiple bundles.